# Does stbi_load() have a limit on the number of pixels of the read picture

Tags: c++, opengl

I use stbi_load() failed to load the picture, but no error was reported.

```
unsigned char* data = stbi_load("world_test.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannel, 0); 
if (data) 
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else 
{
    cout << "load image failed" << endl;
}
```

This "world_test.jpg" is a 43K * 21k JPG picture and the function stbi_load() cannot read the picture. But the previous 21k * 10K "world.jpg" can be read. The other properties of the two pictures are the same. Is it because the picture pixels are too large?

Comment: Did you debug inside stbi? By my count the bitmap corresponding to your jpg is around 3.6GB in size, which overflows a 32-bit int. Is your process 64bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header file itself has [something to say](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h#L190-L206) on this:

```
// Note that stb_image pervasively uses ints in its public API for sizes,
// including sizes of memory buffers. This is now part of the API and thus
// hard to change without causing breakage. As a result, the various image
// loaders all have certain limits on image size; these differ somewhat
// by format but generally boil down to either just under 2GB or just under
// 1GB. When the decoded image would be larger than this, stb_image decoding
// will fail.
//
// Additionally, stb_image will reject image files that have any of their
// dimensions set to a larger value than the configurable STBI_MAX_DIMENSIONS,
// which defaults to 2**24 = 16777216 pixels. Due to the above memory limit,
// the only way to have an image with such dimensions load correctly
// is for it to have a rather extreme aspect ratio. Either way, the
// assumption here is that such larger images are likely to be malformed
// or malicious. If you do need to load an image with individual dimensions
// larger than that, and it still fits in the overall size limit, you can
// #define STBI_MAX_DIMENSIONS on your own to be something larger.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. But I also have a little question about how the pixel limits here are calculated. For example, the pixel of my 21K x 10K picture is 21600 x 10800 x 3 = 
 699840000, it is significantly larger than 16777216, but this picture can still be read.

Comment: You mis-read the comment. That 2**24 limit is *per dimension*. The total size of your image is 700 MB, which is < 2 GB. The other image is 3.6GB and that is too large for a signed int.

Comment: Fine,thank you very much. It seems that higher resolution map cannot be used.